# How can I build application with different Extension's product flavor?

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

I am building an application with Flutter.
I have a package that is called `flutter_appcenter_bundle`

product flavor of package

```
flavorDimensions "distribute"
    productFlavors {
        appCenter {
            dimension "distribute"
        }
        googlePlay {
            isDefault true
            dimension "distribute"
        }
    }
```

It requires appCenter or googlePlay flavor for the build.

But in my application, I have different product Flavors

```
  productFlavors {

        manager {
            applicationId "-------"
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
        }

        saleAgent {
            applicationId "------"
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
        }
        
    }
```

How can I implement in my product flavor or for the whole application one of the extensions product flavor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue by using `missingDimensionStrategy`

Sample code from my application `build.gradle`

```
   defaultConfig {
        //...
        //if you want to use, general setting
        missingDimensionStrategy "distribute", "appCenter"
    }
    flavorDimensions "app"
    productFlavors {
        
        manager {
            dimension "app"
            //...
            //if you want to use, flavor-based setting
            //missingDimensionStrategy "distribute", "appCenter"
            
        }

        saleAgent {
            dimension "app"
            //...
            //if you want to use, flavor-based setting
            //missingDimensionStrategy "distribute", "googlePlay"
        }
        
    }
```